# Calculate the line integral$ \int_\gamma{\frac{d\xi}{\xi^4+1}}$ by partial fractions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Calculate
$$ \int_\gamma{\frac{d\xi}{\xi^4+1}}$$

$y(t)$ is the circumfernce $x^2+y^2=2x$

I tried this for the parametrization.
$$x^2+y^2=2x$$
$$x^2-2x+y^2=0$$
$$x^2-2x+1+y^2=1$$
$$(x-1)^2+y^2=1$$
$$z_0=1, R=1$$

$$\gamma(t)=1+e^{it}, \,\,\,0\leq t\leq 2\pi$$

I did partial fractions, but i get confused in this part:
$$\frac{1}{\xi^4+1}=\frac{1}{2i(\xi^2+i)}+\frac{1}{2i(\xi^2-i)}$$

$$ \int_\gamma{\frac{d\xi}{\xi^4+1}}=\frac{1}{2i}\int{-\frac{1}{\xi^2+i}+\frac{1}{\xi^2-i}}$$

How do I apply the cauchy formula?
$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma{\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz}$$

Comment: i'm trying to understand the residue theorem but I didn't understand him. :c

Comment: If you asked the poster of the answer for clarification they, or another user, would likely respond.

Comment: which part of apply cauchy's formula are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

You can still do, with $\omega$ a square root of $i$,
$$
\frac1{\xi^2+i}=\frac1{2i\omega}\Big(\frac1{\xi-i\omega}-\frac1{\xi+i\omega}\Big),
$$
and similarly for the other one.

Comment: Thank you very much c: